# NPM dependency that imports/requires from the app's root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, es6-modules

Let's say I create an app called `App`. It installs an npm dependency called `package`.

Now let's say `package` requires that `App` has the following file structure:

- App/

  - node_modules/

    - package/

      - index.js
      - package.json
  - folder/

    - file.js
  - index.js
  - package.json

Within `App/node_modules/package/index.js`, it needs to import/require the file located at `App/folder/file.js`.

For example:

```
import File from "../../folder/file";
```

Is this the best way to do this? Is there any way I can reference the App's root in the import instead of needing to use `../../`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not the best way to do it. Modules should not require from their users.

Use dependency injection instead - let your user pass you the objects you require:

**package/index.js**

```
let File = null;

function init (fileModule) {
    File = fileModule;
}

export init;

// ...
```

This way you can pass the `File` object from your main app:

**App/index.js**

```
import { init } from 'package';
import File from './folder/file';

init(File);
```

How you design the API to pass your "middleware" is up to you. The above is just a suggestion. You can pass it as an argument to a constructor for example:

```
const package = new Package(File);
```

This is in fact how frameworks like Express works. It allows Express to be extended without it knowing the structure of your code:

```
app.use(someMiddleware); // Express never "requires" your middleware
                         // instead it allows you to pass middleware to itself
```